# Drag + scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

with jquery.Draggable and its option `containment` I was able to setup a draggable box within a wrapper. Say that the wrapper is 1000 x 1000 pixel large, I'd like to put it within a viewport div that is only 100 x 100 pixel large with overflow: scroll set.

How can I make the dragging of my 10x10px box make the inner div scroll within the viewport div when dragged towards its margins?

I've tried with the scroll option but it didn't work.

To clarify:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example in the Draggable documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#scroll It describes your situation exactly ;)

Nice pictures by the way!